# How to manipulate Jquery Accordian Header text value

Tags: jquery

I am having a Jquery Accordian , which creates nested Accordians based on the search result  .

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DBYLk/25/

Initially While Fetching the Data from the Database i am fetching text it in absolute path  (POPCORN***Bucket)

But while displaying it in accordian i need to show  only the relative path .(Bucket)

And when clciked on the Accoridan Header , (Bucket ) i need to send the whole POPCORN***Bucket , so that the search will not break .

(This is a shoppping cart application and Bucket might exists for some other category and search will give wrong results)

This is the code that is responsible for showing the header on Jquery Accordians.

```
html+="<div><a href='#'>" + response[i] + "</a></div><div id ='sample'></div>";
```

While displaying i can show the last value after the **3 stars** , but when clciked on that , i need to send the whole to the search . please let me know how this can be possible ??

Means i need to somehow store the both the absolute and relative paths under `<div><a href='#'>" + response[i] + "</a>`

**My question can be simplified , i can store the absolute path in href attribute , how to retrive that the href attribute value when clicked on that ??**

Comment: My question can be simplified , i can store the absolute path in href attribute , how to retrive that the href attribute value when clicked on that ??

Comment: use a `data-attrName` attribute and retrieve with `$(selector).data('attrName')`)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are appending many divs with the same `id` which is wrong. `<div id="sample">`
Secondly this is made somewhat harder by your JSON structure.  Do you have the ability to modify that at all?  This would make things much easier to handle.

However you can store the entire "path" via jQuery's `data` attribute and replace the `basePath` with nothing e.g.

```
var tempName = response[i].replace(selectedeleemnt + "***", "");
html+="<div><a href='#' data-path='" + response[i] + "'>" + tempName + "</a></div><div id ='sample'></div>";
```

Also the `PopCorn` in your JSON needs to be uniform as currently you have `PopCorn` and then `Popcorn***`

Handling the data thereafter is a matter of manipulating the `selectedeleemnt` by doing a check if it `hasData` and then using that instead of the `headerText`.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/DBYLk/33/