# How to retrive the href value when selected on the accordian header

Tags: jquery

This is my JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DBYLk/31/

When clciked on the Accoridan Header how can i retrive its a href value ??

I could able to retrive the text, but not its href value ??

This is my function

```
function createAccordian(activateEvent, activateUi) {
    var selectedeleemnt = activateUi.newHeader.text();
    var selectedeleemnthrefvalue = $(this).closest("a").attr("href");
   alert(selectedeleemnthrefvalue);
```

Comment: This is basically the same as your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103941/how-to-manipulate-jquery-accordian-header-text-value hence I am voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Please enlighten me : how does jquery dom navigation  relates to : duplicates IDs ,  JSON structure ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir the previous question, right at the bottom states `My question can be simplified , i can store the absolute path in href attribute , how to retrive that the href attribute value when clicked on that ??` Which in my opinion is pretty darn similar, the OP should modify his previous question which he posted a mere 25 minutes beforehand rather than clutter up SO with two questions wanting the same result.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Oh , he edited it later. ok I agree. ( me 2)

Comment: @RoyiNamir thanks buddy, don't like impatient OP's double-posting in the hope that they get their answer quicker! Just have to look at the OP's question to answer ratio to figure that he's a `help vampire` as @barmar likes to call them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/DBYLk/32/

Changed to this :

```
function createAccordian(activateEvent, activateUi) {
    var selectedeleemnt = activateUi.newHeader.text();
    var selectedeleemnthrefvalue = $(activateEvent.target).find("a").attr("href");  // notice here
                                            ^                     ^
                                            |                     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

- ps change `attr` to `prop`
- Your `this` is not what you think. that's why you have parameter as `activateEvent`
- `closest` is not for next elements. but only for prev parents.(including itself if matched)

Comment: Please see this fiddle,this always gives me the same value http://jsfiddle.net/DBYLk/34/